# Why normal repeated multiplication of power algorithm is not efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, exponential

As the question , i dont understand why we need some algorithm like exponential by squaring or modular exponentiation for calculating the power of a number.

For example, i have a repeated multiplication algorithm like this :

```
def expt_mul(a, n):
    r = 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        r *= a
    return r
```

a multiplied by itself n times , so the complexitiy is O(n), why it's not efficient?

Comment: Efficiency is relative. Why have O(n) when you can have O(log(n))?

Comment: The complexity is O(b), not O(n) (or we must assume n=b) :)

Comment: Just to point out that sequential multiplication isn't efficient:  For the special case of computing a^4, your code takes 3 multiplies.  But you could do it as `a2=a*a; a4 = a2*a2;` which takes only 2.  There's a lot written about this, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring.

Comment: O(log(n)) provides an upper bound, but no theoretical lower bound exists, so the best way to answer your question is to do statistical tests using the language, operating system, etc. that your product uses.

Comment: It's worth noting (but not on an answer) that in this case O(n) is considered an exponential algorithm, since the input itself is Ω(log n) in size. So, if you are talking about a b-bits number, the O(n) algorithm is really O(2^b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some algorithms require raising numbers to very large powers. Algorithms from cryptography in particular come to mind, such as the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

While your algorithm might be fine for most everyday tasks, when you're dealing with exponents that are very large, it becomes unfeasible to use, so exponentiation by squaring is used instead.

> > why we need some algorithm like exponential by squaring or modular exponentiation for calculating the power of a number.

Note that exponentiation by squaring does not achieve the same thing as modular exponentiation. The first is an efficient algorithm to raise an entity to a certain integer power, while the latter is a method to compute an expression of the form `(a^b) modulo c`, where the algorithm used for exponentiation is not particularly relevant.

Answer (score 6):

In encryption, for an example, it's common to do exponentiations where the exponent can be on the order of 2<sup>100</sup> or more.  Assuming you can do 10<sup>10</sup> multiplications per second, you're talking about needing something on the order of 10<sup>20</sup> seconds.  Expressed that way, you might shrug and say "so what?", so let's convert that to years:  10<sup>20</sup> seconds / 3600 sec/hour / 24 hr/day / 365.25 days/year / 14E9 years/current age of universe => over 226 times the current age of the universe!  Contrast that with a logarithmic time algorithm, which will do 2<sup>100</sup> exponentiation in a few hundred operations--almost instantaneously from your perspective.